# Importing data from .csv file to the sqlite database in IOS. FMDB

Tags: iphone, sqlite, fmdb

In my application I need to import data from csv files into sqlite database.

For working with sqlite I use FMDB library, because it is  easy to use:)

Help me please, 
how to import data from csv file to a table?

I have a table created, corresponding to a table in csv file, so it should be ease to import.

I looked at solutions around the internet, and found terminal commands for sqlite such as

```
".mode csv"
".separator ';'"
".import mycsvfile.csv mytablename"
```

But when I try to execute this sql statements in FMDB, it fails..

My source code:

```
   [db beginTransaction];
   NSString *query1 = @".mode csv";
   NSString *query2 = @".separator ';'";
   NSString *query3 = @".import mycsvfile.csv mytablename";

   BOOL result = [db executeUpdate:query];
   result = [db executeQuery:query2];
   result = [db executeQuery:query3];

   [db commit];
```

Here after stepping over BOOL result = [db executeUpdate:query]; result equals to FALSE, indicating that it was error..

After turning on logging in FMDB, it says "incorrect syntax" in my queries.

But why does this statements work in OS X's sqlite?

Note: when i am trying to execute this commands in OS X terminal, in sqlite3, all works correctly.

Comment: can you display your .csv file structure..

Comment: Hi! I solved this problem by manually reading csv file line by line and executing sqlite insert statements with that data

Comment: If someoune is still interested in the solution, now there is an open-source library for importing CSV to SQLite — https://github.com/dodikk/CsvToSqlite

Answer (score 3):

The .import command that you are using isn't part of SQLite itself, rather it is part of the SQLite CLI (Command Line Interface) shell.   Docs for this tool are [here](http://www.sqlite.org/cli.html).  You can download the source code for the CLI tool (file is shell.c, I think) as part of the SQLite distribution from sqlite.org.

If you want to import CSV data in an iOS app to SQLite you'll need to do the manual parsing of the CSV file yourself, as well as inserting the data into tables in your SQLite database.